# How to perform a checked cast?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I am new to Generics and am having an issue.

Consider the following code:

```
public class A {}
public class B extends A {}

public <T extends A> T getB()
{
    A test = new B();
    Class<B> clazz = B.class;
    if (clazz.isInstance(test))
    {
        return (T)test;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This generates an Unchecked cast warning.  on the `return (T)test;` line.
but clearly I am checking the type with the `if (clazz.isInstance(test))` line.

Is there a way to do a "checked cast"?

I'm not looking to just suppress the warning but actually implement a checked cast.  Unfortunately I can't find information on how to perform a checked cast.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is there a way to do a "checked cast"?

Sure, although it's important to note that it doesn't *really* help you here, because your method is hard-coded to use `B` in a few places. You can perform the cast with:

```
clazz.cast(test)
```

... but that will cast to `B`, not `T`. In particular, suppose I ran:

```
public class C extends A {}

...

C c = foo.<C>getB();
```

How would you expect that to work?

You might want to change your code to something like:

```
public <T extends A> T getB(Class<T> clazz)
{
    A test = // get A from somewhere
    return clazz.isInstance(test) ? clazz.cast(test) : null;
}
```

Then that's fine, because `clazz.cast` will return a value of type `T`, which you're fine to return.

Comment: Perfect!  My actual code was passing in a Class parameter already.  Strange I missed the "cast" function.  Thanks!