# How to ensure the cast checked before serialization

Tags: java

I've built the project and I serialized the ArrayList of objects. It works, but I know it cannot guarantee when deserializing (reading) back the ArrayList. It might encounter the `ClassCastException` How can I do the safe type check when serializing or deserializing?

I've referred to:

1. [Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList<MyVariable>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275623/type-safety-unchecked-cast-from-object-to-arraylistmyvariable)
2. [How to perform a checked cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022518/how-to-perform-a-checked-cast)

But still confused...

Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is part of my code:

```
public void saveData() {
    if (playerList.size() != 0) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut =
            new FileOutputStream("players.dat.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(playerList);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            //System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in players.dat.ser");
         } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
         }

    } else {
        System.out.println("There is no data to be stored.");
    } 
}
```

And the code when loading back

```
public void loadData() {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("players.dat.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        ArrayList<NimPlayer> newPlayerList = (ArrayList<NimPlayer>)ois.readObject();// warning here

        setPlayerList(newPlayerList);
        ois.close();
        fis.close();

     } catch (IOException i) {
        //i.printStackTrace();
        return;
     } catch (NullPointerException n) {
        //System.out.println("no data to be recoverd.");
        //n.printStackTrace();
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
        //System.out.println("players.dat file not found");
        //c.printStackTrace();
        return;
     }    
}
```

Comment: Add `serialVersionUID ` in your class `NimPlayer`.

Comment: So, that will ensure deserialization only load the arrayList with the same `serialVersionUID`, right? Like a key. @SudhirOjha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of type erasure, the best you can say is that it's a raw `ArrayList`, via `instanceof`. You can't do any checks against the generic type parameter.

If you want to do it safely then you can do something like this, checking every single item and creating a new list, but there is an overhead involved.

```
Object read = ois.readObject();
List<NimPlayer> newPlayerList = new ArrayList<>();
if (read instanceof List) {
    for (Object item : (List<?>) read) { 
        if (item instanceof NimPlayer) {
            newPlayerList.add((NimPlayer) item);
        }
        // else { maybe throw exception, or log warning }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you can suppress the warning.

Comment: It's clear. If I want to read it back using `ArrayList`, I need to use `Iterator` to add back the player, right?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use an itera**tor**. My example uses a for-each, which does use an iterator under the hood. But you could also do a standard for-loop with an index. The point is that you do need to iter**ate** in order to ensure type safety, but iteration doesn't necessarily involve an itera**tor**.

Comment: I think this Answer is nicely similar to this other [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20275765/1357094)  on 1 of the questions referenced in this Question .  Nice.